# Angular 11 Unit test for chart.js: Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, chart.js

I am writing tests using Jest for components which uses chart.js to create a line chart. My chart is working totally fine but I am not able to write tests as I am getting the below error:

```
console.error
Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package) 
    at module.exports (D:\charts\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\not-implemented.js:9:17)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/hustcc/jest-canvas-mock solved this for me